# parse error (possibly incorrect indentation ...) when building a cabal file with Haskell2010

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I just had the following error with a Haskell project.
I made a cabal file for a Haskell project to install it properly. This project compiled well when I build my binary with `ghc --make` but when I build my cabal file with `cabal build` , I had the following error:

```
src/Text/MarkIt/Verif.hs:12:3: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

The beginning of my file is :

```
module Text.MarkIt.Verif where
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict as Tr
import Text.MarkIt.Types
import Data.List

class Verif a where
  summary :: a -> Tr.State StatDoc ()

instance Verif MarkIt where
  summary (MarkIt meta blocks) = do
  summary meta
  mapM_ summary blocks  -- This is the boring line

instance Verif Meta where
  summary meta = mapM_ summary (mAuthors meta)
```

I tried to rebuild my executable with ghc and it compile well. I checked if their were no hidden char, tabulation, incorrect end of line, ... nothing!
I finally removed the following line from my cabal file :

```
default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Then, my cabal file was build and installed fine !

**Does someone could explain me why this cabal option cause a such problem at this precise point of my file?**

**What is different with the Haskell 2010 language specification to cause this problem ?**

Comment: I would be supprised if that builds, you need to indent your `do` block. Perhaps you mixed tabs and spaces?

Comment: Are you sure `ghc --make` does not skip the file (for example because you did not pass it to the command line)?

Comment: I used the Geany function to convert tabulations to space but it doesn't modify the file (And don't change the error)

Comment: ghc doesn't skip the file and build fine. It return [21 of 32] Compiling Text.MarkIt.Verif ( Text/MarkIt/Verif.hs, Text/MarkIt/Verif.o )
Linking Main2 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, GHC is in Haskell 98 mode, which enables the following relaxation from the standard:

> In Haskell 98 mode and by default (but not in Haskell 2010 mode), GHC is a little less strict about the layout rule when used in do expressions. Specifically, the restriction that “a nested context must be indented further to the right than the enclosing context” is relaxed to allow the nested context to be at the same level as the enclosing context, if the enclosing context is a do expression.
>
> https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bugs.html#context-free-syntax

A comment in the GHC source explains further:

> strictly speaking non-standard, but we always had this on implicitly before the option was added in 7.1, and turning it off breaks code, so we're keeping it on for backwards compatibility.
>
> https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/blob/d0b45ac6984f245bce9de7ffcc7dad4a0046d344/compiler/main/DynFlags.hs#L2310

When you enable the Haskell2010 mode in your cabal file, that bug gets fixed, and the syntax of your file is rejected. so `do` blocks must be indented further than the enclosing context,

```
    summary (MarkIt meta blocks) = do
      summary meta
      mapM_ summary blocks
--  ^ indented
```